# Array Getting Treated Like a Variable in Another Function

Tags: c++

My array is being treated like a variable when I pass it out of a function. I have tried multiple fixes and none have seemed to work. In the ReadInRound function everything from the file writes out for the file I'm reading in. I would like to bring the Update[] array to the Append function so I can append the file I'm writing to.

```
struct MasterFile{
string round, ID, fName, lName, league, team;
double mins, twoPTA, twoPTM, threePTA, threePTM, fTA, fTM, perTwo, perThree, perFT, fouls, turnovers, points;};

struct Header{
string record, fileName, date, round;};

struct Footer{
string record, fileName, date, round;
int recordCount;
double mins;};

struct UpdateFile{
string record, action, round, ID, fName, lName, league, team;
double mins, twoPTA, twoPTM, threePTA, threePTM, fTA, fTM, fouls, turnovers, points;};

int main(){


Header header[1];
Footer footer[500];
MasterFile Master[500];
UpdateFile Update[500];
MasterFile NewMaster[500];

int x = 0; // Round counter
double roundCount = 0;
int u = 0; // New master counter
int w = 0;

x = ReadInRound(Update, Master);

ReadInMaster();

Append(roundCount, Master, Update, x, NewMaster);

Out(w, NewMaster, u);




system("Pause");
return 0;}
double ReadInRound(UpdateFile Up[],  MasterFile Master[]){

ifstream RoundFile;
RoundFile.open("roundData.txt", ios::in);

string recordType = "H,D,T";
double points = 0.0;
Header header[1];
Footer footer[500];
UpdateFile Update[500];

int x = 0;

if (RoundFile.is_open())
{//Header 
    getline(RoundFile, header[x].record, ',');
    getline(RoundFile, header[x].fileName, ',');
    getline(RoundFile, header[x].date, ',');
    getline(RoundFile, header[x].round, '\n');
    x++;
    while (!RoundFile.eof())
    {//Player Data
        getline(RoundFile, recordType, ',');

        if (recordType == "T")
        {//Footer
          //footer[x].record = recordType;
            getline(RoundFile, footer[x].record, ',');
            getline(RoundFile, footer[x].fileName, ',');
            getline(RoundFile, footer[x].date, ',');
            getline(RoundFile, footer[x].round, ',');
            RoundFile >> Update[x].points;
            RoundFile.ignore(100, '\n');
            x++;
            break;
        }
        Update[x].record = recordType;
        getline(RoundFile, Update[x].action, ',');
        getline(RoundFile, Update[x].round, ',');
        getline(RoundFile, Update[x].ID, ',');
        getline(RoundFile, Update[x].fName, ',');
        getline(RoundFile, Update[x].lName, ',');
        getline(RoundFile, Update[x].league, ',');
        getline(RoundFile, Update[x].team, ',');
        RoundFile >> Update[x].mins;
        RoundFile.ignore(100, ',');
        RoundFile >> Update[x].twoPTA;
        RoundFile.ignore(100, ',');
        RoundFile >> Update[x].twoPTM;
        RoundFile.ignore(100, ',');
        RoundFile >> Update[x].threePTA;
        RoundFile.ignore(100, ',');
        RoundFile >> Update[x].threePTM;
        RoundFile.ignore(100, ',');
        RoundFile >> Update[x].fTA;
        RoundFile.ignore(100, ',');
        RoundFile >> Update[x].fTM;
        RoundFile.ignore(100, ',');
        RoundFile >> Update[x].fouls;
        RoundFile.ignore(100, ',');
        RoundFile >> Update[x].turnovers;
        RoundFile.ignore(100, '\n');
        points = (Update[x].twoPTM * 2) + (Update[x].threePTM * 3) + (Update[x].fTM * 1);
        x++;
    }
    //Up = Update;

}
else
{
    cout << "Round File failed to open.\n";
}

return x;}

void Append(double& roundCount, MasterFile Master[], UpdateFile Update[], int& x, MasterFile NewMaster[]){
int w = 0;
for (int d = 0; d < x; d++)
{
    int e = 0;
    if (Master[e].ID == Update[d].ID)
    {
        if (Update[d].action == "C")
        {
            NewMaster[w].ID = Update[d].ID;
            NewMaster[w].fName = Update[d].fName;
            NewMaster[w].lName = Update[d].lName;
            NewMaster[w].league = Update[d].league;
            NewMaster[w].team = Update[d].team;
            NewMaster[w].mins = Master[e].mins + Update[d].mins;
            NewMaster[w].twoPTA = Master[e].twoPTA + Update[d].twoPTA;
            NewMaster[w].twoPTM = Master[e].twoPTM + Update[d].twoPTM;
            NewMaster[w].threePTA = Master[e].threePTA + Update[d].threePTA;
            NewMaster[w].threePTM = Master[e].threePTM + Update[d].threePTM;
            NewMaster[w].fTA = Master[e].fTA + Update[d].fTA;
            NewMaster[w].fTM = Master[e].fTM + Update[d].fTM;
            NewMaster[w].perTwo = ((Master[e].perTwo) + (Update[d].twoPTM / Update[d].twoPTA)*100) / 2;
            NewMaster[w].perThree = ((Master[e].perThree) + (Update[d].threePTM / Update[d].threePTA)*100) / 2;
            NewMaster[w].perFT = ((Master[e].perFT) + (Update[d].fTM / Update[d].fTA)) / 2;
            NewMaster[w].fouls = Master[e].fouls + Update[d].fouls;
            NewMaster[w].turnovers = Master[e].turnovers + Update[d].turnovers;
            NewMaster[w].points = Master[e].points + Update[d].points;
            w++;
            e++;
        }
        else if (Update[d].action == "D")
        {
            e++;
        }
    }
    if (Update[d].action == "A")
    {
        NewMaster[w].ID = Update[d].ID;
        NewMaster[w].fName = Update[d].fName;
        NewMaster[w].lName = Update[d].lName;
        NewMaster[w].league = Update[d].league;
        NewMaster[w].team = Update[d].team;
        NewMaster[w].mins = Update[d].mins;
        NewMaster[w].twoPTA = Update[d].twoPTA;
        NewMaster[w].twoPTM = Update[d].twoPTM;
        NewMaster[w].threePTA = Update[d].threePTA;
        NewMaster[w].threePTM = Update[d].threePTM;
        NewMaster[w].fTA = Update[d].fTA;
        NewMaster[w].fTM = Update[d].fTM;
        NewMaster[w].fouls = Update[d].fouls;
        NewMaster[w].turnovers = Update[d].turnovers;
        w++;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You really should use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of naked arrays.

Comment: All of your arrays *are* variables.

Comment: I should have included the structs. Basically what is happening is it goes from filling out as an array to becoming variables in my debugger.

Answer (score 0):

In `double ReadInRound(UpdateFile Up[],  MasterFile Master[])` the parameter is named `Up`, but you keep updating the local `UpdateFile Update[500];`.

Change them into `Up`.

Comment: I did, I commented it out. It should be near the end of the while loop in ReadInRound.

Comment: @EricJesse NO, arrays cannot be assigned that way. You can assign element-by-element if the assignment operator of `UpdateFile` is defined correctly though.

Comment: Assuming I kept it as Update and made it a parameter (which when I didn't have it local and kept it in main it would make it a variable instead of an array) would that possibly solve my problem?